# Installing multiple folders

Tags: yocto

I'm relativly new to the whole Yocto Project.

Basically I want to add multiple folders to the image:

```
do_install() {

    install -d ${D}/etc/wpa_supplicant
    install -m 0777 wpa_supplicant-wired-eth0.conf ${D}/etc/wpa_supplicant
    install -d ${D}/mydata
    install -d ${D}/mydata/certs
}
```

wpa_supplicant needs a conf file in /etc/wpa_supplicant. So I install the folder and copy my custom conf file there.

This works FINE

Simultaneously I want to install a certificate folder under /mydata/certs where I can later upload my certificates for the wpa_supplicant.

But when I do do that Yocto tells me the old install vs shipped error

```
mywpa-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: mywpa: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /mydata
  /mydata/certs
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
mywpa: 2 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: mywpa-1.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: mywpa-1.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yocto/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/mywpa/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.31833
ERROR: Task (/home/yocto/yocto/sources/poky/../meta-mydata/meta-mywpa/recipes-mywpa/mywpa/mywpa.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Previously I just worked I had ONE folder per recipe and just added

```
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/etc"
```

So my question is basically: How do I install two folders in two different directories? Or is impossible in a single recipe and I have to use two recipes?

Comment: whats wrong with `FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/etc /mydata"`? (not completely sure if mydata needs the leading slash, but you'll be able to work that out :P )

Comment: Wow, this seems to have worked. It's really this simple ? :D 
The only Issue I have is, that it seems like the bitbake process took way longer this time

Comment: I actually doubt that this triggers a much prolonged `bitbake` execution time, at least not directly by the fact that `FILES_${PN} We have many cases in which that variable is *very* complex, thats a really common usecase. - (Addendum: please accept the answer if you're fine with it, so others can also make use of it. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FILES_${PN} +=` expression can be almost arbitrarily complex, as long as it is static at parse time. So you should be able to just expand it as needed:

```
FILES_${PN} += " \
  ${sysconfdir}/etc/wpa_supplicant \
  /mydata \
"
```

If there's any problems with that approach, please update the question then I can look into it.